# Using str_extract to extract numbers in the middle and the last letter of the file name

Tags: r

My file names are as follows: "20210824_P_103_D"
("Date_species_light_treatment").
I am writing a loop to upload all my data frames and want to add columns based on the file names.
I added the date column by using:

```
mutate(date = str_extract(file,
                              pattern = "\\d{8}"))
```

I added the species by using:

```
mutate(coral_species = str_extract(file, 
                                 pattern = "[[:alpha:]]"))
```

I am trying to add the light (the 3 last digits) and the treatment (the last letter) and can't figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to split at the `_`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = str1) %>%
     separate(col1, into = str_c('col', 1:4), sep = '_', convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
      col1 col2   col3 col4 
     <int> <chr> <int> <chr>
1 20210824 P       103 D
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "20210824_P_103_D"
```